# Using data from sql table within condition in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to coding.

I am trying to select data from a table in SQL then use this data as part of a condition in a PHP If statement. The code I am using appears below. The echo $row["endsequence"]; line shows the correct value has been retrieved from the database, but the record isn't being updated as I need it to be in the final part of code. Any help much appreciated.

```
<?php

$result = filter_var($_GET['result'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$action = filter_var($_GET['action'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pupilid = filter_var($_GET['pupilid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$pathwayid = filter_var($_GET['pathwayid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$stageid = filter_var($_GET['stageid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$resourceid = filter_var($_GET['resourceid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "planit";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT endsequence FROM resources WHERE id= " . $resourceid;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["endsequence"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

if ($result == 'fail' && $action == 'tryagain' && $row['endsequence'] == "2")              {

    $sql1 = "UPDATE pupils SET activeresourceid = (SELECT nextresourceid FROM resources WHERE id=$resourceid) WHERE id=$pupilid";

}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by $result=='fail'?

Comment: You are using the variable $result for two different things: the get parameter and the database result. Use different names for these two different things.

Comment: Thanks. Have just changed one of the $result variables to a new name but still isn't working.

Comment: Snoop the $result=='fail' relates to information passed to the page. The IF statement works as it should using the $result and $action variables but not with the $row['endsequence'] == "2" even though the code is showing that $row["endsequence"]  is 2 when echoed.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something. "Sanitize" functions like the ones mentioned here are often highly flawed and totally inadequate.

Comment: Consider do your query in while loop and assign a variable to $row["endsequence"] and run the if statement